# Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'A | B'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am fetching data from an url and if a certain condition is met, the data is loaded inside a type B or its superclass A. When the data is loaded in B, typescript does not recognise its properties. 
I get the following error with the code below:

> Property 'doB' does not exist on type 'A'

```
class A {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    doA() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
class B  extends A{
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message)
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    doB() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter: A|B  = new B("world");
greeter.doB()
```

Comment: Sorry I just fixed it. But the error is the same. It does not compile yet. Try by yourself https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: No I believe you. I suspect that `A|B` when `B` extends `A` is going to be treated basically like `A` by the type system.

Comment: The error makes sense. How can you call `doB` with certainty if the defined type for var `greeter` is `A` *or* `B`  (and `A` does not have member `doB()` defined)?

Comment: Do you want to know why you get the error or what is your question?

Comment: greeter is of type either A or B I am assuming. So why typescript does not allow me to call a method of B ?

Comment: Because `greeter` could also be an instance of `A` which would break type safety *if* the transpiler did allow it.

Comment: Having a type of `A | B` only allows you do access properties that exist on *both*. From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types): *"If a value has the type `A | B`, we only know for certain that it has members that both `A` and `B` have. In this example, `Bird` has a member named `fly`. We can’t be sure whether a variable typed as `Bird | Fish` has a `fly` method. If the variable is really a `Fish` at runtime, then calling `pet.fly()` will fail."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error makes sense. How can you call `doB` with certainty if the defined type for var `greeter` is `A` *or* `B`  (and `A` does not have member `doB()` defined)?

> greeter is of type either A or B I am assuming. So why typescript does not allow me to call a method of B ?

Because `greeter` could also be an instance of `A` which would break type safety *if* the transpiler did allow it.

Having a type of `A | B` only allows you do access properties that exist on both.

Answer (score 3):

When you define a type as `A|B`, this is a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) in TypeScript.

When using a union type, typescript by default would only allow you to use the properties that are present on both the types. In this case, an example of that would be `doA`.

But if we can only access those, then the type won't make much sense. To access a property that is only present on one of the instances, all you have to do is to make sure it has the correct instance type or Type Gaurd. In this case, that can be done with:

```
let greeter: A|B  = new B("world");
if(greeter instanceof B) {
    // Do just B things
} else if(greeter instanceof A) {
   // Do only A things
}
```